# Cube of a number using Visual Basic using For..Next

Tags: vba, visual-studio

This is what I've come up with but it doesn't seem to compile. http://rextester.com/live/AHLL27136

```
dim n, var As integer
For var = 1 to 10
n=InputBox("enter")
msgbox "The cube of number is" & n^3
Next var
```

Comment: This code is vba, but you are testing it at a vb.net website.  By the way, your vba code runs fine!

Comment: @BrianMStafford oh..didn't realise that. Thanks for the affirmation.